# Error al ejecutar un bot de telegram

Tags: python, telegram

Estoy intentando programar un bot de telegram que se pueda añadir a un grupo y guarde las fotos que se envíen al mismo.

Es el primer bot que programo y tampoco tengo muchísima idea así que quizá las preguntas son un poco simples, perdón por adelantado.

Hasta la fecha he copiado un ejemplo de bot que hace eco de cualquier mensaje que se envíe al grupo, le he añadido un filtro para que identifique las imágenes.

Ejecuto el bot en sublime text y todo funciona bien cuando entro en la conversación con el bot, funciona el eco e identifica las fotos.

El problema viene cuando añado el bot a un grupo. Envío el comando start y el bot responde, pero más allá ni hace los ecos ni identifica fotos. En la consola, y no siempre, aparece esta linea de error:

Conflict: terminated by other getUpdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is running

Entiendo que está recibiendo varias actualizaciones diferentes y que el código que está corriendo en mi ordenador no sabe cómo gestionarlas (esto es así?)

La pregunta sería cómo hacer para que el bot funcione correctamente en un grupo.

El código:

```py
import logging

from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters

# Enable logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    level=logging.INFO)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


# Define a few command handlers. These usually take the two arguments update and
# context. Error handlers also receive the raised TelegramError object in error.
def start(update, context):
    """Send a message when the command /start is issued."""
    update.message.reply_text('Hi!')


def help(update, context):
    """Send a message when the command /help is issued."""
    update.message.reply_text('Help!')


def echo(update, context):
    """Echo the user message."""
    update.message.reply_text(update.message.text)

def guardaImagen(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text("Has enviado una imagen")

def error(update, context):
    """Log Errors caused by Updates."""
    logger.warning('Update "%s" caused error "%s"', update, context.error)


def main():
    """Start the bot."""
    # Create the Updater and pass it your bot's token.
    # Make sure to set use_context=True to use the new context based callbacks
    # Post version 12 this will no longer be necessary
    updater = Updater("1027057970:AAFA62euU-XJkgiJCLRplsFDMb-enS1IohA", use_context=True)

    # Get the dispatcher to register handlers
    dp = updater.dispatcher

    # on different commands - answer in Telegram
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("help", help))

    # on noncommand i.e message - echo the message on Telegram
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, echo))

    # cuando llega una imagen llamamos a la función guardar imagen
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.document.category("image"), guardaImagen))

    # log all errors
    dp.add_error_handler(error)

    # Start the Bot
    updater.start_polling()

    # Run the bot until you press Ctrl-C or the process receives SIGINT,
    # SIGTERM or SIGABRT. This should be used most of the time, since
    # start_polling() is non-blocking and will stop the bot gracefully.
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Vale, resuelto, era una chorrada.

En el botfather de telegram hay que deshabilitar el modo privado dentro de bot settings -> group privacy

Ahora ya funciona como debe.